# What's the best way to store the minimum differential data of a changed object?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

I have an object which contains many properties, of many datatypes which is the settings for a search of a large cache. I would like to pass the values which have been changed on this object from the base settings and only the changes. I would also like to pass this information as a very short string.

So what I need is a technique for doing this in C# .NET 4 (pseudo code follows):

```
var changes = Diff(changedobject, baseobject);
return changes.ToShortString()
```

and later on a remote machine which only knows the object

```
var changedobject = CreateObject(diffstring)
```

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I do not have a code for you but this should be pretty clear

> Create a metadata class which using
>   reflection, gets the properties of the
>   object and caches the getter method of
>   each. Then for each property, it does
>   the same if it is a complex property,
>   etc ... so you get an object graph
>   similar to your class. Then when
>   passed two objects of the same type,
>   this recursively loops through the
>   metadata and calls getter in order to
>   compare and returns the result. You
>   can also make it generically typed.

Implementaion would be something like this:

```
public class Metadata<T>
{
    private Dictionary<string, Metadata<T>> _properties = new Dictionary<string, Metadata<T>>();
    private MethodInfo _getter;

    private void BuildMetadata()
    {
        Type t = typeof (T);
        foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in t.GetProperties())
        {
            // ....
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The CSLA.NET framework uses reflection to walk the properties and fields of a type and write them to a hash table.  This hash table is then serialized and stored.

The type is called `UndoableBase`, in the CSLA.NET project.

I can't remember if it records diffs, but the premise is that you need a copy of the state before (in the CSLA case, this would be the previously serialized item).

Assuming you have a copy of an item (an actual copying, not a reference) as a source of originals, then you can use reflection to check each property and add it to the hash table if it has changed.

Send this hash table over the wire.

**An alternative** and one that I would look at more, is to prefix your serialized item with bit flags denoting what fields are provided in the forthcoming stream.  This will likely be more compact than a hash table of name values.  You can include this in your reflection solution by first sorting the fields / properties alphabetically (or by some other means).  This won't be version tolerant, however, if you store this serialized data across versions of the type.